# re-parenting explained with an example

Tags: c, linux, process

I am trying to understand the re-parenting process in linux. So when the parent process exits abruptly the child process is adopted by the init process. This is re-parenting.
I am not able to understand the below code that shows how re-parenting works.
First the process is forked and the child process runs. 
The first "printf" statement is executed.
Then sleep() is called. Why is "terminated" printed after this?
Is the parent process ever called?
Please somebody explain me how does this work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  if (fork() == 0) {
    // child process
    printf("My parent's PID is %d\n", getppid());
    sleep(2);
    printf("My parent's PID is %d\n", getppid());
  } else {
    // parent process
    sleep(1);
  }
  // both processes
  printf("Terminated\n");
}
```

The output:

```
My parent's PID is 18892
Terminated
shell $ My parent's PID is 1
Terminated
```

Comment: What happens to the normal program flow in the child after it executes the second printf?

Comment: i just want to know why does the code output that

Comment: Because after the 2nd printf, execution resumes after the else body, which outputs "Terminated".